# Multivariable calculus involving considering symmetries and change of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, symmetry, multiple-integral

From a lesson that I had, there was this integral: (B denotes the unit ball)

$I_1=\iiint_{B} x^n+y^n+z^n dV = 3\iiint_B z^n dV$ and then the teacher used change of coordinates to spherical polar to deal with this integral and the rest is fairly standard. However I had a few questions. (Also the equality holds by symmetry, as stated by my teacher, if anyone is wondering)

$1)$ Say I do $3\iiint_B x^n dV$ instead and then use the spherical polar, would this give the same answer? (I believe it would because the unit ball is spherically symmetric)

$2)$ I later encounter a problem where I am required to evaluate $I_2=\iint_{D} (x+y)^{2n+1} dA$, where $D$ is the unit disc and I tried to do the same thing by saying $I_2=\iint_{D} (2y)^{2n+1} dA$ because I thought this is symmetric in a similar sense of the unit ball above. However my teacher said this approach is invalid. So why exactly is the first one valid and the second one isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. By symmetry, $\iiint_Bx^2\,\mathrm dV=\iiint_By^2\,\mathrm dV=\iiint_Bz^2\,\mathrm dV$.
2. Your teacher is right. You could do that if $n=0$, or you could say that the integral of $x^{2n+1}$ is equal to the integral of $y^{2n+1}$, but otherwise you are integrating a different function. Try to express exactly why you think that the integral of $(x+y)^{2n+1}$ is equal to the integral of $(2y)^{2n+1}$, using a symmetry principle. I suspect that you will not be able to do it.

Comment: ah I think I understand! If let say I am dealing with $\int\int_{D} x^{2n+1}+y^{2n+1} dA$ instead then I suppose I can use the symmetry property right?

Comment: Yes! That is a fine example indeed.

Comment: How should I approach the second question, if you dont mind helping me? I know the integral will be $0$ but I don't see clearly why

Comment: You can apply a symmetry principle here: for each $(x,y)\in D$, $(x,-y)\in D$ too, but the value of your function at $(x,y)$ is the symmetric of the value of the function at $(x,-y)$ (this is where the fact that exponent is an odd number is used.). Therefore, the integral of your function in the upper half of $D$ is minus the integral of the function in the lower half of $D$.